# using an html triangle for a list

Tags: html, hover

How can I show ► next to the link when hovering over a list of links?

```
&#9658;

<ul>
  <li><a href="">link</a></li>
  <li><a href="">link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a:hover:before {
    content:'\25BA';
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8da9h/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

CSS

```
ul li:hover .tri{display:none}
ul li:hover .tri{display:inline}
```

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li><span class="tri">&#9658;</span><a href="">link</a></li>
  <li><span class="tri">&#9658;</span><a href="">link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This might work better to keep things from jumping horizontally, especially if you toggle `visiblity` instead of `display`.

Answer (score 0):

```
li:hover:before {content: "►";}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/7y8Hk/